# Вопрос по методу PUT

Tags: веб-программирование, http, rest

Можете подсказать, вопрос задали на собеседовании, точно не понимаю, что произойдет, вопрос: "что будет если вызвать метод  PUT для несуществующего ресурса, если допустим передать значение с id = 5"

Я ответил, что скорее всего придет ошибка, либо создаться новый ресурс, в интернете тоже пишут по - разному, что будет ошибка, может новый создаться, ошибки могут быть разные..

Вот варианты ответов:

1. Ошибка 404: Сервер вернет статусный код 404 (Not Found), чтобы указать на то, что запрашиваемый ресурс не найден. Это означает, что сервер не смог найти ресурс, на который вы пытаетесь выполнить операцию PUT.
2. Создание нового ресурса: В некоторых случаях, сервер может интерпретировать запрос PUT, как попытку создать новый ресурс с указанным идентификатором. В этом случае, сервер может создать новый ресурс с указанным идентификатором.
3. Ошибка 405: В зависимости от конфигурации сервера, также возможен возврат статусного кода 405 (Method Not Allowed), чтобы указать на то, что метод PUT не разрешен для данного ресурса. Это может произойти, если сервер не поддерживает создание новых ресурсов посредством метода PUT или если метод PUT запрещен для конкретного ресурса

Что лучше отвечать в итоге?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Можете дать пожалуйста понятие `PUT` для вашего контексте?

Comment: все зависит только от сервера. любой метод может обрабатываться так, как захочет сервер

Comment: @Grundy вопрос таки, наверное, в целом про предназначение PUT-запроса.

Comment: @teran судя по [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-put) - запрос может как обновлять, так и создавать ресурсы, при этом также в некоторых случаях может возвращать 415 результат